# formData.delete() not a known property

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, form-data

Am using a FormData object to upload a file , i want the functionality of deleting file from FormData, but i get an error delete property does not exist on FormData object

```
formData.delete(fileName)
```

Code

```
upload(){
    let formData = new FormData();
    let inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
    let files: FileList = inputEl.files;
    formData.append('uploadFile', files, files.name);
}

delete(fileName){
    formData.delete(fileName);
}
```

Comment: Share your code

Comment: 'upload(){
let formData = new FormData();
let inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
let files: FileList = inputEl.files;
formData.append('uploadFile', files, files.name);
}

delete(fileName){
formData.delete(fileName)
}'

Answer (score 0):

Variables cannot be shared between methods, so you'll need to use a property, or call the method and get a result.

The example below stores the `formData` in a private property and references it within each method with `this.formData`.

```
private formData: FormData;

upload() {
    this.formData = new FormData();
    let inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
    let files: FileList = inputEl.files;
    this.formData.append('uploadFile', files, files.name);
}

delete(fileName){
    this.formData.delete(fileName);
}
```

Comment: Still I get property 'delete' does not exist on type FormData

Comment: Where are you calling it? Sounds like you have the classic scope issue, which will probably be solved with an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

As Safari and IE doesn't support delete property, take a look on this page
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete